# Doxygen related question. Commentings same stuff in different files

Tags: doxygen

I'm using doxygen for commenting code. There is, for example, two files:

**test1.cpp**:

```
/**
* @namespace SomeNamespace
* @brief Describe it
*/
namespace SomeNamespace
{
   ...
}
```

**test2.cpp**:

```
// Put comment about namespace again?
namespace SomeNamespace
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comment same stuff in different files, comments get concatenated in Doxygen output. I experience it at least when commenting both function declaration and function body.